# How does the computer keep track of which physical pages are used?

Tags: memory-management, virtual-memory

My book([link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0128000562)) says that if the computer tries to access a virtual memory page that is on the hard-disc it loads that page into physical memory. But how does the computer keep track of which physical memory it should use? Does it look through the page table to find free physical memory?

Comment: The operating system is responsible for that.

Comment: @user253751 Thank you, so the operating system keeps track of which physical pages are free, and gives a free physical page when loading a virtual page from the hard disc?

Comment: The operating system is responsible for all this paging stuff. All the CPU knows is the page tables.

Comment: Yes, the OS looks for a free page in the page table. If none are free, it selects one to be swapped out.

Comment: Thank you both very much!